# ¿Cuál es la ventaja de utilizar un constructor sin parametros?

Tags: atributos

Basicamente es esa la pregunta, que ventajas tiene o para que se utiliza mayormente un constructor que no recibe parametros, osea los constructores por defecto, donde no se inicializa ninguno de sus atributos al crear la instancia. Para poder utilizar sus métodos sin generar espacios en memoria sin sentido?

Comment: Un constructor sin parámetros se utiliza para iniciar un objeto con valores predeterminados, por decirlo de alguna manera crear un objeto por defecto, el que contiene parámetros es para asignar valores diferentes a esos que vienen por defecto.

Answer (score 0):

No es una cuestión de ventajas. Simplemente es obligatorio para crear un objeto, hacerlo mediante un constructor. El constructor por defecto es simplemente una opción automatizada que nos brinda el lenguaje para asegurarse de que SIEMPRE hay al menos un constructor disponible para cada objeto que creemos. Pero no es para ahorrar memoria, ni para que el programa vaya más rápido....ni nada de eso.

Comment: Tambien se puede implementar el constructor vacio declarandolo como privado; esto es para obligar a que cuando se crean nuevas instancias deban declararse con parametros.